# Can't Add Users and Groups Using the AD Browse Button

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, active-directory

I am a *farm administrator* for our SharePoint Foundation 2010 site, and I have been experiencing a permissions problem for the past few months (it has not always been like this) that inhibits me from using the AD searcher when changing site permissions.  When clicking the "Browse" button to search/add/remove users from Active Directory to and from sharepoint groups, I receive the following error:

**Error:
An unexpected error has occured.**

I can search for and see all the users and groups in our Active Directory catalog, this error only occurs when I click the OK button to submit the permission change.  Oddly enough, when I type in the user's domain and username and click the "Check Names" button, it finds the users from AD and I can then add that user to the group.

This behavior is consistent for me whenever I try to make permission changes to anything in our site (doc libraries, lists, files, etc.)

As anyone experience this phenomenon before?  If so, do you have any suggestions?
Thanks!